# change spaces in stacked barplots

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is it possible to reduce the space between the 1st and 2nd bar,3rd and 4th, 5th and 6th, 7th and 8th, juxtaposing bars with the same outcome and different method.
Here's the database infos:

```
> str(st2)

'data.frame':   24 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ Outcome   : Factor w/ 4 levels "LGiT","LGuT",..: 3 3 3 1 1 1 2 2 2 4 ...
 $ Event     : Factor w/ 3 levels "Event 1","Event 2",..: 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 ...
 $ Percentage: num  10.31 8.25 81.44 12.77 15.32 ...
 $ Method    : Factor w/ 2 levels "M1","M2": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Cohort    : Factor w/ 1 level "Cohort 1": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ label     : chr  "10%" "8%" "81%" "13%" ...
 $ sum       : chr  "100.00%" "100.00%" "100.00%" "100.00%" ...
```

Here's the plot code:

```
p7 <- ggplot(st2, 
             aes(x = factor(st2$Outcome:st2$Method), y = st2$Percentage,  
                 fill = st2$Event, group=st2$Event)) +
  geom_bar(aes(alpha=st2$Method), position = position_stack(), 
           stat = "identity", width = .7, colour="black") +
  geom_text(aes(label = st2$label), position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5), size = 4) + 
  coord_flip() 

p8 <- p7 +
  labs(x="Outcome", y="Percentage Values", fill="Legend")+ 
  scale_fill_grey(start=1, end=0.8)+ 
  theme(axis.text=element_text(size=15), 
        axis.title=element_text(size=17, face="bold"), 
        legend.title=element_text(size=13), 
        legend.text=element_text(size=12))

p8 +
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(panel.border = element_blank(), 
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), 
        axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"))
```

Here is my plot:

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: You could try facetting by a variable

Comment: Also, you generally want to give bare column names inside `ggplot` functions, e.g. `aes(x = group)`, not `aes(x = df$group)`. It can lead to errors

Comment: Thank you camille, I used `aes(x = df$group)` cause using just `aes(x = group)` R didn't find group... I don't know why..

Comment: Are you suggesting to use different panels? I know this option but I would prefer just one panel..

Comment: They're not separate panels exactly; you make a facetted plot in one call, then add `facet_wrap`. To get much more help on this, you'll need to post a sample of your data for folks to work with